# Can't upload 14mb file to SkyDrive via LiveSDK from my wp7 device

Tags: windows-phone-7, onedrive, live-sdk

It's not a problem to upload 5mb file but when I try to upload 14mb my application is down.

```
fileStream = // get some file as stream from isolated storage

uploadClient = new LiveConnectClient(session);
uploadClient.UploadCompleted += new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(uploadClient_UploadCompleted);

uploadClient.UploadAsync("me/skydrive", "filename", fileStream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite, null);
```

Exception (see screen shot):

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
Addtional information: NotSupportedException"
```

[image]

When I use BackgroundUploadAsync instead UploadAsync the file is transferred but has size 0.

Anyone knows the solution of this problem?

Comment: There could be many factors in place. Show a code snippet that throws the exception, and show the exception details.

Comment: Could you attach debugger to see what kind of exception you get?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

!!!IT's IMPORTANT
The method UploadAsync should be called only from main application thread